# How to replace multiple tabs with only one tab using python3 + Pandas in a given .csv File

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

i'm trying to replace multiple tabs with only one tab using python3 + Pandas in a given .csv File, but i'm not able to find a way to solve this problem; if my function is:

```
def function(csv_file):

    -remove multiple tabs --> means have a \t \t b ==> a \t \b
    [...]
```

the file must be remain a csv file.

How could i do it?

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add some example data so we can see what you mean.

Answer (score 0):

A csv is just a text file that can be parsed with tailored tools, but can also be read as plain text. So, you can use regex to substitute consecutive `\t` instances.

You still need to provide more details, but take this as a provisional answer.

```py
import re

with open('test.csv', 'r') as fo:
    text = fo.read()

print(text)
print(repr(text))

text = re.sub(r'\t+', r'\t', text)

print(text)
print(repr(text))
```

Output

```
test            sdasdf
asfasdf asdf    asfasdf         asdf

'test\t\tsdasdf\nasfasdf\tasdf\tasfasdf\t\tasdf'

# after regex

test    sdasdf
asfasdf asdf    asfasdf asdf

'test\tsdasdf\nasfasdf\tasdf\tasfasdf\tasdf'
```

Notice the last `print` does not have any consecutive tabs.

Now you can write back to csv.

```py
import os

with open('test_temp.csv', 'w') as fo:
    fo.write(text)

# os.remove('test.csv')
# os.rename('test_temp.csv', 'test.csv')
```

It is a good idea to write a temp file, remove the original, and finally rename the temp. This is so you have a safe copy at all times for odd situations like corrupt file writes, power outages, or any other contingency.

Comment: You are very welcome! Now read [what to do when someone answers](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers). I'm not asking you to accept this question, but comments are meant for clarification. Treat this site more like an encyclopedia and less like a social network, so other users have less lines to read through. And pay it forward by voting up/down on other questions and answers. Welcome to SO!